# Resize/Change HTML element's width when adjacent element added

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to make auto resizable of an HTML element.

So here is my script.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .main{
                background-color: blue;
                width: 500px;
                position: fixed;
            }
            .inner{
                background-color: brown;
            }
            #tag{
                display: inline;
                background-color: aqua;
            }
            input{
                float: right;
                width: auto;
                height: 100%;
            }
            button{
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div class="main">
        <div class = "inner">
            <div id="tag">

            </div>
            <input type='text'>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <script>
        function add(){
            let text = document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = text+"<span>hi</span>";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0xmkgd8/

**Problem is I couldn't make auto-resizing of width**

**Outputs Expected**

- Initially, the input element should be with full width(500px).
- When I click to add the input element's width has to resize based on parent width(500px) and no overflow of elements
- Let say if I click add button once, `Hi` text raise up within `class="inner"` element and input element's width should be reduced based on `inner` class width (i.e) 50px (inner class element) + 450px (input element) = 500px (main class element)

  - whenever the `inner` class width increases, `input` element's width also decreased.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fork of your fiddle, adding more IDs: https://jsfiddle.net/c4yhv7zk/

```
<div class="main" id="main">
    <div class = "inner">
        <div id="tag">

        </div>
        <input id="input" type='text'>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Making so when adding text, it will get the outer width of the main div and of the tag div, subtract them, and then assign them input element.
I've added a 5px margin to avoid overflow and it will hide the input element the subtraction goes under 0.

```
var tagWidth = document.getElementById("tag").offsetWidth;
var mainWidth = document.getElementById("main").offsetWidth ;
var finalWidth = mainWidth - tagWidth - 5;
if ( finalWidth > 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("input").style.width = finalWidth + "px"; 
} else {
    document.getElementById("input").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

And adding "box-sizing: border-box" to avoid issues between browsers:

```
.main{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner{
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#tag{
  display: inline;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input{
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To avoid subtracting those 5px, you could add "float: left" and "float: right" to the #tag and #input element respectively. I didn't do that in this fiddle because I don't know how important the "display: inline" on the #tag element to the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet.let me know if you have any query.

```css
 .main{
                background-color: blue;
                min-width: 500px;
                position: fixed;
                width:auto;
            }
            .inner{
                background-color: brown;box-sizing
            }
            #tag{
                display: inline;
                background-color: aqua;
            }
            input{
                width: auto;
                height: 100%;
            }
            button{
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <div class="main">
        <div class = "inner">
            <div id="tag">

            </div>
            <input type='text'>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <script>
        function add(){
            let text = document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = text+"<span>hi</span>";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is great for automatic resizing of elements. You could fill the *remaining* space of a container with the element and resize the input whenever a new `<span>` has been added to your container.

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById("tag").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>hi</span>');
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  background-color: brown;
}

#tag {
  flex: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div id="tag">

    </div>
    <input type='text'>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```